# Websites for getting fatwas?(according to hanafi fiqh)

Tags: reference-request, hanafi

I have different questions .
Please kindly guide me reliable websites where i can post my questions and i may get answers/fatwas soon

Comment: These kinds of question are a poor fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

These two websites are very popular websites.
https://islamqa.info/en
https://www.islamweb.net/en/

Comment: But none of them gives fatwa according Hanafis fiqh unless it is required. Both rather cover the salafi view.

Answer (score 0):

The website of mufti ebrahim desai. Askimam.org

Comment: Adding the link could be more profitable.